# CSS link to file on harddrive?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to link to a css file on a hard drive (outside of MAMP or similar)? The following isn't working for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="C:\mystyles.css" />
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible due to security issue. What's your final goal here?

Comment: Im doing front end for a site thats in development. I dont fully understand how it all works but all the files are 'cached' (but not by the browser) and theirs a 10 min build cycle, which I would have to run after any changes if I wanted to see them. So as most of my changes will be in a CSS file Im trying to link to it some other way so I can refresh the page to see CSS changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `file:///` protocol.

```
href='file:///C:\mystyles.css'
```

If that doesn't work (and you say it doesnt), then my guess is that it won't work at all due to it being prevented by security features in the browser.

It depends on where you are loading the main HTML content from, but if the main HTML is loaded from the internet then I can understand why the browser might object to loading the CSS from the client machine's local file system.

One final thing to try: You might try setting up a web server on your machine, putting the mystyles.css file into the web folder, and loading it into the page using:

```
href='http://localhost/mystyles.css'
```

I can't really suggest much else, I don't think.

Comment: But won't it look for the file on the *client* machine?

Comment: @Shadow - yes. I thought that's what he wanted.

Comment: Doesn't work. If i drag the file into a browser the link is file:///C:/mystyles.css Im testing this with firebug and which uses " instead of ' but im guessing that wont change anything.

Comment: @jdln - ah well, pity. If that didn't work, then my guess is that @Shadow Wizard will be correct, that it's not possible due to security. I'll edit my answer to clarify that. BTW - No the single quotes vs double quotes is irrelvant; both are valid.