# HTML file looking for CSS in file:///C:/?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working a project. The website is originally built in Ruby on Rails and I have to rebuild it in static HTML & CSS for now.

Now when I'm linking the stylesheet to the page it doesn't work because it's looking in the directory `"file:///C"`, despite me linking it to the local directory.

```
<link href="dist/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I try the file in the directory `(file:///C:/page/dist/css/)` it works fine.

Help would be appreciated

EDIT:

Ah, found out there was a base href attritube. Never used, or knew about it,

```
<base href="/">
```

Thanks for the comments though!

Comment: try ./dist/css/screen.css

Comment: Where was your file originally located when this was not working?

Comment: Relocate your stylesheet to the same directory as your `*.html` file is in.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<link href="../dist/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/screen.css">
```

Comment: I've tried that already, but it doesn't work. It's still looking in my C: drive.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124922/css-link-to-file-on-harddrive

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/css/screen.css"> try @AlessioJordaan

Comment: I want it to work the other way around. It's looking in my C drive, but I want it to look in the local directory. I've never had this problem before. I've tried searching for "C:" in the file, but with no results.

Comment: Look this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-on-another-folder

Answer (score 0):

try using this with **./**

```
<link href="./dist/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah there was a base href attritube

```
<base href="/">
```

Thanks for the comments though!